# super class's __init__ is not called using dataclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I am making a job class by inheriting from `asyncio.Future` with some custom attributes, and expect the job instance functions like the original Future.

When I call `job.set_result` inside a coroutine, it raises a `Future object is not initialized error`, then I tried to get future initialized by call `asyncio.ensure_future` and the same error appears.

I tried more and find that the future is usually created by `loop.create_future()`, however, there is no options to create my custom future.

Below is an example, How can I get my custom future initialized?

```py
import asyncio
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Job(asyncio.Future):
    job_task: Callable
    real_future: asyncio.Future = None
    something: str = None

    def schedule(self):
        async def run():
            res = await self.job_task()
            self.set_result(res) # raise error, future not initialized
            return res
        self.real_future = asyncio.ensure_future(run())

async def main():
    async def task():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return 1
    job = Job(task)
    job.schedule()
    await job

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: @user4815162342 wow, it worked. thanks, can you make an answer so I could accept this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Future` is not a dataclass, but your `Job` class inherits from it and uses the `@dataclass` decorator. This results in failure to invoke `Future.__init__` and consequently failure to initialize the future object.

To fix the issue, don't use the `@dataclass` decorator in the first
place. Instead, write an explicit `__init__` that sets the necessary attributes, and invokes `super().__init__()` to initialize the `Future` correctly.

Comment: @downvoter How is this answer "not usefu" - it was posted as a comment, and the OP said it fixed their issue. There can be other ways to fix it, but if this answer is actually incorrect in some way, then please write a comment describing it, so that I can improve it.

Comment: It was me, I thought about starting a discussion but decided to just post my issues as an answer. I think it's not useful because it solves the problem by introducing something unnecessarily dangerous.

Comment: @Arne My answer was meant to imply to not use the `@dataclass` decorator in the first place, __replacing__ its use with a manual `__init__`. I now see that it wasn't explicit and could be misunderstood as suggesting to write an explicit `__init__` and keep using `@dataclass`, which was not my intention. I've now amended the answer to be explicit about it.

Comment: ah, fair enough.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call the superclass constructor yourself, something that dataclass's `__init__` can't do [because of reasons](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/issues/142). But you also shouldn't try to re-implement `__init__` yourself, since it [is not exactly intuitive](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/af50c84643ce21cfbdfdabbdfae6bd5e1368c542/Lib/dataclasses.py#L501-L548) and you might mess up.

The Right Way To Do It (given that you want to keep using the `@dataclass` decorator) is leveraging the `__post_init__` hook that dataclasses provide:

```py
@dataclass
class Job(asyncio.Future):
    job_task: Callable
    real_future: asyncio.Future = None
    something: str = None

    def __post_init__(self)
        super().__init__()

    def schedule(self):
        async def run():
            res = await self.job_task()
            self.set_result(res)  # works now
            return res
        self.real_future = asyncio.ensure_future(run())
```